# There are too many data that dotted line seem to be straight line in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

As the picture below
In the subplot (2,1,1), the linestyle is '--'， but seems like a straight line.
In the subplot (2,1,2), the linestyle is ':', it seems better but also have the same problem.
How can I get a concise dotted line?
[image]

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],df['RESULT_DESC'],'o')
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],(xbar,) * num)
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],((UCL,) * num),'--')
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],((LCL,) * num),'--')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],df['range'],'o')
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],(rbar,) * num) 
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],((UCLR,) * num),':')
plt.axhline(y=UCLR, xmin=starttime, xmax=stoptime)
plt.plot(df['START_DATETIME'],((0,)*num),':')
```

Comment: What code did you use to obtain these graphs?

Comment: J...S Is totally right, How can you get this plot with out writing code?

Comment: @J...S   I add the code ,but for some reason I can't give my data out. Sorry for that.

Comment: @U8-Forward Added~

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, even with 1e6 randomly distributed x values between 0 and 1. You have to add more description about the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you have too many points unsorted. Your code is plotting a lot of lines back and forth, individually they'd all be dashed / dotted but one over the other they look much more like a straight line (I don't know why exactly not a straight line, but I'd guess because matplotlib internally does not always start dashing exactly from the start point to save some time - otherwise plotting thousands of line like in this case would take forever).

The solution, since you're just plotting a straight line, is to restrict the input to two points, the first and last one. Not having your data I replicated it with random data, see below:

from matplotlib

```
import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10000)
plt.plot(x,[1]*len(x), '--')
plt.text(0, 0.9, 'Wrong - too many points')
plt.plot([np.min(x), np.max(x)], [0]*2, '--')
plt.text(0, 0.1, 'Correct - only two points')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: that's it imo - and i always sorted my random test data... :-)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !